# Update system wide gsettings proxy settings on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dbus, gio, gsettings

Is there a way to get/set **system wide** gsettings? I'm trying to get/set proxy settings from a C++ program which is owned by root.
Currently within my program I'm making system calls to the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy mode 
gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'auto'
gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy mode
```

When I print out the system call response of the **get** system calls I always read back **'none'**.
After some research I understand gsettings is user based and that each session has it's own DBUS_SESSION_ADDRESS but is there a way either by system call or within C++ programmatically using Gio::Settings to apply these proxy settings system-wide in Ubuntu?

Comment: You want https://docs.gtk.org/gio/class.Settings.html#vendor-overrides or https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-lockdown.html.en